Smoke sim behaving strangely

Above is a fresh scene I created to demonstrate the problem, just to make sure none of the objects in my scene are interfering. All I did here is subdivide the cube and add Quick Smoke, without adjusting any settings. When I hit play the smoke drifts strongly to the side along both x and y axes, then flattens out, well below the top of the domain.
I've played with some of the simulation settings with no improvement, but I have no idea what the problem is so I can't work toward a solution. This has persisted since at least 4.0 (I'm on 4.2.0 currently) and I don't have any addons that are supposed to affect physics.


Can you share your file? I'd start by going to the scene tab and checking if gravity is in Z, if there are wind or field forces and other things. Also check if there is animation for the domain or for the source object. Also check if the source object has rotation (the domain doesn't)

Perhaps supply the example file via blend-exchange so someone can analyze your problem...  then edit your question after the upload to paste the resulting HTML upload text.

just tested in Blender 3.6: it works normally (baked, type: All)

I downloaded your file, works perfectly fine on both Blender 4.3 Alpha and Blender 4.2

I'm quite sure it works on all Blender versions as I've never experienced any such bugs in simulations - maybe try making a new scene or try re-installing blender 4.2 LTS - it should work fine.

After going through my addons one at a time I determined this bug was caused by the Wiggle Bones addon. The script must have interfered with the physics simulation. So now I know not to use wiggle bones with other simulations in the same file.
